# Launching a TestFlight build takes multiple seconds (App Store apps are fine)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, testflight

NB: This question was originally [posted to the Apple Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1109327#1109327) (login required).

## Problem

I have an iPhone 6 Plus running iOS 8.1.3 (12B466), for the most part it functions as expected. However any apps I install either via TestFlight or build and run on the device with Xcode all take multiple seconds to launch.

The icon will become dark and after 3, 4 or 5(!) seconds the app will launch, occasionally the entire phone will crash during launch. This happends with any app install via TestFlight not just my own apps. Apps installed via the App Store are fine and launch immediately.

I also have an iPhone 6 adn 5S, these launch TestFlight app immediately as expected.

Anybody else having this problem?

### Steps taken to resove:

- Reset phone and restored from back up (did not fix)
- Checked the logs (cannot see anything that might be useful)
- Restarted the phone (hundreds of times!!!!)

## Other info

The only other thing I have noticed about my iPhone 6 Plus is from within an app calls to UIImagePickerController also take multiple seconds this is true for (at least); my own apps, iMessage, Tweetbot.

### Console output

#### Run #1 (Luas app)

```
Mar  4 17:02:56 Richards-iPhone kernel[0] <Notice>: 006747.446970 wlan0.A[282] AppleBCMWLANCore::dumpWmeCounters():  per AC tx counters: 2355413 596034 1940 1256, rx counters: 3638640 0 0 0 
Mar  4 17:02:56 Richards-iPhone kernel[0] <Notice>: 006747.446982 wlan0.A[283] AppleBCMWLANCore::dumpWmeCounters():                AWDL: Tx 0 0 0 0      Rx: 0 0 0 0 
Mar  4 17:02:57 Richards-iPhone syncdefaultsd[611] <Notice>: (Note ) marked "com.me.keyvalueservice" topic as "enabled" on <APSConnection: 0x146e29200>
Mar  4 17:03:01 Richards-iPhone kernel[0] <Notice>: xpcproxy[628] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/67627D3D-73E3-4CEA-8A13-8ADBCBDC7925 (sandbox)
Mar  4 17:03:01 Richards-iPhone locationd[60] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
Mar  4 17:03:01 Richards-iPhone SpringBoard[53] <Warning>: Received memory warning.
Mar  4 17:03:01 Richards-iPhone Luas[628] <Error>: assertion failed: 12B466: libxpc.dylib + 71820 [2A02E77C-4317-32E2-92FB-E37AF8747B2E]: 0x7d
Mar  4 17:03:01 Richards-iPhone Unknown[628] <Error>:
```

#### Run #2 (Luas app)

*This launch cause the phone to restart (possible Springboard restart?)*

```
Mar  4 17:05:06 Richards-iPhone SpringBoard[53] <Warning>: Compiler connection failed with XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED
Mar  4 17:05:09 Richards-iPhone kernel[0] <Notice>: xpcproxy[634] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/67627D3D-73E3-4CEA-8A13-8ADBCBDC7925 (sandbox)
Mar  4 17:05:09 Richards-iPhone Luas[634] <Error>: assertion failed: 12B466: libxpc.dylib + 71820 [2A02E77C-4317-32E2-92FB-E37AF8747B2E]: 0x7d
Mar  4 17:05:10 Richards-iPhone SpringBoard[53] <Warning>: Received memory warning.
Mar  4 17:05:09 Richards-iPhone Unknown[634] <Error>: 
Mar  4 17:05:10 Richards-iPhone locationd[60] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
```

#### Run #3 (Luas app)

```
Mar  4 17:09:15 Richards-iPhone kernel[0] <Notice>: xpcproxy[655] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/67627D3D-73E3-4CEA-8A13-8ADBCBDC7925 (sandbox)
Mar  4 17:09:15 Richards-iPhone SpringBoard[638] <Warning>: Received memory warning.
Mar  4 17:09:15 Richards-iPhone Luas[655] <Error>: assertion failed: 12B466: libxpc.dylib + 71820 [2A02E77C-4317-32E2-92FB-E37AF8747B2E]: 0x7d
Mar  4 17:09:15 Richards-iPhone Unknown[655] <Error>: 
Mar  4 17:09:16 Richards-iPhone locationd[60] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
```

#### Run #4 (Vail app)

*Different app but still multiple second wait after tapping it in Springboard.*

```
Mar  4 17:09:45 Richards-iPhone locationd[60] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
Mar  4 17:09:48 Richards-iPhone kernel[0] <Notice>: xpcproxy[656] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B88A4E35-32DF-4C9C-8B28-066FAC93835F (sandbox)
Mar  4 17:09:48 Richards-iPhone vail[656] <Error>: assertion failed: 12B466: libxpc.dylib + 71820 [2A02E77C-4317-32E2-92FB-E37AF8747B2E]: 0x7d
Mar  4 17:09:48 Richards-iPhone SpringBoard[638] <Warning>: Received memory warning.
Mar  4 17:09:48 Richards-iPhone Unknown[656] <Error>: 
Mar  4 17:09:48 Richards-iPhone locationd[60] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the crash logs? It would be telling if it's your app crashing versus Spring Board.

Comment: @benzado Updated with console output during launch

Comment: So two things appear every time: SpringBoard reports a memory warning, and your app fails an assertion inside libxpc. That's kind of interesting, because XPC is used to display views belonging to another process, such as (I think) the UIImagePickerController.

Comment: @benzado The "assertion failed" is a red herring I think, every app seems to do it, even built in apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the [Apple Dev Forum thread](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1112086#1112086) for detailed info.

Xcode 6 had trouble showing me all the installed profiles and only has the ability to delete them one at a time. iPhone Configuration Utility no longer works for deleting profiles (on devices running iOS 8+) and/or under Yosemite.

## tl;dr

I used Xcode 5.1.1 to remove most of the provisioning profiles and now apps launch instantly!